# grab price only using php preg_match

Tags: php

I tryed to grab the price from the html source 
here is the part of the source

```
 <h1>
    <span id="ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_lblRegion">Product Name</span>
    <strong id="ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_divFiyat" class="price">
        749 €
        <small>
            2007 TL
            <small class="nightday">
                <span id="ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_lblNightDay">Un related detals</span></small></small>
    </strong>
</h1>
```

As you see here it is very specified id. Here is my code..

```
 $Tour_Price ="/<span id=\"ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_divFiyat\" class=\"price\">(.*?)<\/span>/i";
        preg_match($Tour_Price , $Tur_Fiyat, $Result_Price);
        echo "<strong>Result:</strong>".$Result_Price[1];
```

My code works perfectly in other parts of the source. But price only doesnt. 
Please shoot ideas. Thanks to all interested :)

Comment: Why `preg_match`? Are you aware of `DOMDocument`: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php ?

Comment: That markup looks horrible. Is that SharePoint?

Comment: You have no: ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_divFiyat   with that span id.  check th eid's.

Comment: JonatanRomer, I do copy/paste but not working still.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

You specify `<span` instead of `<strong` at the beginning of your regex.

But in your source span and strong have different ids.

Comment: Actually this line of code changes.<span id="ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_lblRegion">Product Name</span>
I have to use <strong

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code:

```
$Tour_Price ="/<strong id=\"ctl00_PageHeaderContentPlaceHolder_divFiyat\" class=\"price\">(.*?)<\/strong>/is";
preg_match($Tour_Price , $Tur_Fiyat, $Result_Price);
echo "<strong>Result:</strong>".$Result_Price[1];
```

Notic: The changes are `span` to `strong` and `{...}/i` to `{...}/is`

Comment: That's exactly my answer.

Comment: misstyping of span to strong is ok but it is not the problem. Thanks for "/is" heads up but still not working.

Comment: If i try it with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it's working for me.